# How to add foreign fields to objects inside an array based on a value of an object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following collection (sectors):

```
[
    {
        sector: "IT", 

        organizations: [
            {
                org: "ACME", 

                owners: [
                    "Josh", 
                    "Fred"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I also have another collection (owners):

```
[
    {
        name: "Josh", 
        age: 65, 
        male: true, 
        location: "LA"
    }
]
```

I want the aggregation query to do the following:

1. For each sector document, go though each organization.
2. Find an owner document corresponding to index 0 of the owners array.
3. Add the { name, age, male } fields to the organization.

I want to get this result:

```
[
    {
        sector: "IT", 

        organizations: [
            {
                org: "ACME", 

                owners: [
                    "Josh", 
                    "Fred"
                ], 

                name: "Josh", 
                age: 65, 
                male: true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am writing this in Node.js. This is my current code:

```
await Sector.aggregate([
    // Perhaps something with $lookup?

    { $match: query },

    { $skip: skip },
    { $limit: limit }
]);
```

I am totally new to aggregation with MongoDB. Can anyone tell me how it's done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation

- `$addFields` and `$arrayElementAt` helps to get the first element by looking with `$map`
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$lookup` to join collections
- `$group` to reconstruct the array

Here is the code

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      organizations: {
        $map: {
          input: "$organizations",
          in: {
            firstName: { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$this.owners", 0 ] },
            org: "$$this.org",
            owners: "$$this.owners"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$organizations},
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection2",
      "localField": "organizations.firstName",
      "foreignField": "name",
      "as": "join"
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { join: { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$join", 0 } } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "organizations.age": "$join.age",
      "organizations.location": "$join.location",
      "organizations.male": "$join.male",
      "join": "$$REMOVE"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "organizations": { "$push": "$organizations" },
      "sector": { $first: "$sector" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8d58OIgN7Ga)**